# how to consider user modification in result and consider them in VRP

Tags: traveling-salesman, jsprit, vehicle-routing

I am working on one VRP(Vehicle routing problem) to make plan of pickup and drop service, As VRP is NP hard problem user edits plan according to their requirement.Now I am planning to consider their modification while preparing plan. where should I start for same?

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. And in any case, "where should I start" is not really a good SO question. Can you give more details?

Comment: Let me explain with example, let us suppose we need to solve one VRP problem and we have created one VRP plan for problem and after than one person will review plan and modify it according to their experience or need.what i want that I should be use his intelligence in next time plan. means I should be able to find a pattern in his plan and use same pattern for future VRP plans.let us suppose he is putting two address in plan so in next plans those address should be served together only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to incorporate expert knowledge into a VRP optimiser would probably be using constraints. Have a look at [JSprit documentation of constraint](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough%20%20%20Constraints.md) as a starting point, if you are using JSprit. If the available type of constraints are not enough to model the knowledge your expert has, you may need to dig deeper and play with cost function and search strategy.

Inferring the constraints automatically from the improvements the expert made to a previous route is going to be difficult. There may be many reasons for any change in a route - it's difficult to tell why the expert made a change if they don't tell you explicitly. If possible,  ask the expert to define the constraints explicitly. For example, instead of just changing a route so a job from address X and a job from address Y are served by vehicle 1, the expert will tell your system "Address X and address Y always have to be served by the same vehicle".

By the way, since this is a rather general algorithmic question, you might try to post it on the [Compute Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).